# Why appending a pandas DataFrame to a python list convert the resulting df in Series but assigning it works as expected?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm filtering out a big dataframe in subsequent steps, willing to temporary store filtered out ones in a list to eventually tamper with them later.

When I append the filtered dataframe to the list (i.e. `temp.append(df[df.isna().any(axis=1)])`), the item is stored as pandas Series, while if I assign it to the same list it appear as a dataframe (as expected):

```
check = []
check[0] = pdo[pdo.isnull().any(axis=1)]
check.append(pdo[pdo.isnull().any(axis=1)])
type(check[0]), type(check[1])

Out: (pandas.core.frame.DataFrame, pandas.core.series.Series)
```

Comment: WRONG QUESTION: see [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64182574/why-appending-a-pandas-dataframe-to-a-python-list-convert-the-resulting-df-in-se#comment113497089_64182592)

Answer (score 0):

Is your full line of code is the following?:

```
temp = temp.append(df[df.isna().any(axis=1)])
#^^^^^^
```

Comment: Nope. `pdo` is the df, `check` is the preassigned `list()`. Edited the question accordingly. Code above is an excerpt from jupyter notebook.

Comment: Actually, my code is wrong: neither assignment (`IndexError`) nor appending works... I'm resorting to use `dict()`.